# Changing edgecolor in matplotlib legend markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I've checked the kwargs for matplotlibs legend but can't find this option available. When I plot the legend the color key beside the text will be correct, however there is a blue egdecolor to the key that I'd like to remove.

Wondering if anyone knew how to get at this attributed.

```
cm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(random.sample(sns.palettes.color_palette('Reds').as_hex(), len(sns.palettes.color_palette('Spectral').as_hex())))

con.plot(column='suffix', 
         figsize=(15,15), 
         linewidth=2, 
         legend=True, 
         cmap=cm, 
         legend_kwds={'loc': 'lower center', 
                      'ncol':len(con.columns), 
                      'frameon':False, 
                      'markerscale':3.0,
                     'bbox_to_anchor': (0.5, -0.05)})

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The above code is from a geopandas plot() function. This code returns the below image where we can see the blue rim to the legend key colors:
[image: Plot]

Comment: The edgecolor of the key will be taken over from the artist that you label. If this has a blue edge, the legend will show it as well.

Comment: I second @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, but if that's not helpful to you, then you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you both for you comments edits have been made. I'm unsure what the term "artist" refers to in the comment?

Comment: Oh so geopandas apparently creates a wrong legend?! But due to [this line](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/0f2ca1a802ad6814f5185b45288961b66f51a054/geopandas/plotting.py#L609) this shouldn't happen with the newest version. Which version are you using? It's [this fix](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/807), which is available from version 0.5 onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [this line](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/0f2ca1a802ad6814f5185b45288961b66f51a054/geopandas/plotting.py#L609) this shouldn't happen with the newest version. It's [this fix](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/807), which is available from version 0.5 onwards.

If you are stuck with an older version and cannot update to 0.5 or higher, you might get away with specifying the markeredgewidth through the matplotlib rcParams.

```
with plt.rc_context({"lines.markeredgewidth" : 0}):
    # your code here
    df.plot(....)
```